# Plotly: Hide colorbar on Surface plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, colorbar

I can't figure out how to hide the colorbar on a Plotly Surface plot.

The code I am using is:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 9, 10)
y = x
z = np.linspace(0, 99, 100).reshape((10, 10))

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z
    )
)

fig.update_layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis_title='x',
        yaxis_title='y',
        zaxis_title='z'
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Here are the few things I have tried:

```
fig.update_coloraxes(showscale=False)
```

```
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)
```

```
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        colorscale=None,
        colorbar=None,
        coloraxis=None
    )
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This works for Plotly 5.17.0:

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        showscale=False    # <<<<<<<<<<
    )
)
```